# Regex en consulta sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo un fichero con una columna que contiene los valores siguientes:

```
Valor
KTM;SCOTT;FOCUS;BERRIA;TREK
CASCOS
GUANTES
FOX;ROCKSHOCK
```

El caso es que quiero hacer un `LEFT JOIN` con otro fichero si alguno de estos valores se encuentra en este otro fichero. El segundo fichero tiene la columna siguiente:

```
Concepto
CASCOS
FOX
ROCKSHOCK
KTM
FOCUS
GUANTES
```

Cómo podría recorrer el primer fichero y hacer la búsqueda del valor? Había pensado en un regex pero no estoy seguro de si hay una forma mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Más que un `left join`, deberías usar un `inner join`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
inner join t2 
on '%;' || t2.concepto || ';%' like ';' || t1.valor || ';';
```

[Aquí tienes la prueba](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c2b2/11/0), pero vamos: en general no es buena idea usar un `like` en una expresión de este tipo ya que puede penalizar mucho el resultado en tablas muy grandes.

Comment: Esto no funcionará pues el campo 'concepto' contiene un conjunto de valores y estás concatenando cualquier cosa delante y detrás de esa cadena.

Comment: Algo así, debería funcionar: `on  ';' || t1.valor || ';' like '%;' || t2.concepto || ';%';`

Comment: @Panri93, he cambiado la consulta para que haga lo que se pide, echa un vistazo